# Can I get the MSYS2 Bash as an optional shell on Windows OpenSSH server? (Not Windows 10)

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, openssh

**Goal:** Add MSYS2/MinGW64 BASH as an optional shell to an existing OpenSSH server with automation purposes in mind.

**Constraints:**

- Not Windows 10. WSL is not an option.
- Shared work environment. Shouldn't "pee in the other kids' pool" beyond what's avoidable.
- Keep PowerShell Core as primary SSH shell.
- Have MSYS2/MinGW64 available with minimal overhead as needed.
- Automation is key.

**Setup:**

Following instructions from various Microsoft sources:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6

I have successfully gotten PowerShell over SSH working. However, I have the (more-than-occasional) need to run the MSYS2/MinGW Bash shell.

**What KINDA works:**

- running bash in ssh from the CLI: ssh dms3@somehost C:/MSYS64/usr/bin/bash.exe --login *(No prompt, can't re-enable in PS1)*
- Setting the Bash exe as a subsystem: *(same as above in best-cases, freezes in others)*
  Subsystem   bash       c:/MSYS64/usr/bin/bash.exe --login

Both are possibly "good enough" for automation.

**What would work, but I'd rather not do:**

- Running MSYS sshd as a second SSH server on a different port.
- Running Bash after logging into Powershell

**What I can't do**

- Use a Linux VM.
- Use WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this helps, but I'm using the included Win10/11 OpenSSH server. On the Windows SSH server I use CMD as my default shell & I've setup an Environmental variable for my user acct that acts as an alias to start the MSYS shell:

Variable name :  MSYS

Value :  `"msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -msys -no-start -where C:\Tools\msys64\home\\%UserName%"`

NOTE:  the MSYS64 directory has to be in your environmental PATH variable so `msys2_shell.cmd` can be found.

From my SSH client I manually log into the Win SSH server with the std SSH command:

`ssh user@host`

which gets me the default CMD prompt shell on the server.  At the prompt I use the MSYS Environmental variable I created as an alias command by typing:

`%msys%`

This launches the MSYS Bash shell & sets my working directory to my MSYS home directory. However, there's a problem. The MSYS environmental variable HOME is set to the Windows UserProfile path and the .bashrc file is not read.  To fix the MSYS HOME, I've added ' export HOME="/home/username" ' to the .bashrc file. After using the %msys% variable as an alias to log in, I run the following command to read the .bashrc file:

. /home/username/.bashrc

The MSYS HOME value gets changed as a result of the export command I added.

If my Win SSH server was set to use the Powershell shell as the default shell I would try using the Powershell environmental alias construct:

`$env:MSYS`

to start the MSYS Bash shell. This does not work however. Powershell does not accept the environmental variable as an alias for a command. I suggest setting up an alias in the SSH server's Powershell $PROFILE.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Run in administrative powershell

`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`